# Google BigQuery bq load for certain columns?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a dataset of `.orc` files. I use the CLI to load my data in BQ using the `bq load` command in the `gcloud` utils. My data have 4 columns. The third column duplicates the 4th, but I'd like to keep the 4th column. Is there a way to only ingest certain colums with `bq load` of `orc` files?

Comment: Did you try to specify a schema in the `bq load` command with only your 3 column and to add the param `--allow_jagged_rows`? But I think it won't work. It's not allowed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-orc). Does your file is big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ingest only some columns, you can specify the columns in the end of the command:

```
bq load --source_format=ORC DATASET.TABLE gs://YOU-FILES_LOCATION COLUMN1:TYPE, COLUMN2:TYPE, ...
```

Lets suppose two scenrios:

1. In the first scenario you don't have a table in `BigQuery` and you want to load only some fields of you `ORC` file. If you run the command above specifying some fields, will be created a table with only that fields.
2. In the second scenario, you already have a table in `BigQuery` with `NULLABLE` fields. In this case, if you run the command above specifying the fields, you will load only that fields of your data into the table and the other fields will be `NULL` for that rows.

Please let me know if it helps you with your problem.